# Assign decision variables regarding the index of my dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, tuples, pyomo

I'm building a model using pyomo and I'm struggeling to assign the correct input to one of my decision variable.

Here's my 2 inputs that I'm using:

List`N` which is my list of employees

```
N = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

And a dictionary `EmployeesWE` with as key the employee ID from the list above and as value a list of tuples containing all weekend in the planning horizon:

```
EmployeeWE = {'0':[(2, 3),(9, 10),(16, 17),(23, 24)],
 '1':[(2, 3),(9, 10),(16, 17),(23, 24)],
 '2':[(2, 3),(9, 10),(16, 17),(23, 24)],
 '3':[(2, 3),(9, 10),(16, 17),(23, 24)],
 '4':[(2, 3),(9, 10),(16, 17),(23, 24)],
 '5':[(2, 3),(9, 10),(16, 17),(23, 24)],
 '6':[(2, 3),(9, 10),(16, 17),(23, 24)],
 '7':[(2, 3),(9, 10),(16, 17),(23, 24)],
 '8':[(2, 3),(9, 10),(16, 17),(23, 24)],
 '9':[(2, 3),(9, 10),(16, 17),(23, 24)]}
```

So `(2,3)` is the first weekend, `(9,10)` 2nd, `(16,17)` 3rd and `(23,24)` the last.

The decision variable is binary,  if worker n works at weekend i it's 1 otherwize 0.
My code is the following:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = ConcreteModel()
model.weekends = Var(((workers, weekends) for workers in N for weekends in EmployeeWE[workers]), within=Binary, initialize=0)
```

Here's an extrat of the print function of the decision variable:

```
Key           : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      ('0', 2, 3) :     0 :     0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
     ('0', 9, 10) :     0 :     0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
```

Instead of the days of the weekend I would like the index of my tuple. For example instead of (2,3) it would be one. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Here is an example below and a couple points...

1. Not sure why you are using strings to hold integers, it doesn't really matter, but pyomo can make set from either and if they are integers, just go with it.
2. when you declare a pyomo variable, if you want it to be indexed by 2 sets, you do it as I've got below.
3. For the weekends, it isn't clear what you are doing with the dictionary... there is only "one set of weekends" so you don't need to create one for each employee, right?
4. I just used integers to index the weekends in a dictionary.  After the model computes, I could use those integers to go back into the weekend dictionary to pick up the labels or whatever from the selected indices, which is the set model.W

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

employees = ['X18', 'E22', 'B9']   # employee ID's.  Could also be integers or names or ____
weekends  = {   1: 'Mar 3-4',
                2: 'Mar 10-11',
                3: 'Mar 17-18'}    # the values here could be tuples of integers or whatever...

model=pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.E = pyo.Set(initialize = employees)
model.W = pyo.Set(initialize = weekends.keys())

model.X = pyo.Var(model.E, model.W, domain=pyo.Binary)

model.pprint()
```

#### Yields:

```
3 Set Declarations
    E : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'X18', 'E22', 'B9'}
    W : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {1, 2, 3}
    X_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    E*W :    9 : {('X18', 1), ('X18', 2), ('X18', 3), ('E22', 1), ('E22', 2), ('E22', 3), ('B9', 1), ('B9', 2), ('B9', 3)}

1 Var Declarations
    X : Size=9, Index=X_index
        Key        : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
         ('B9', 1) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
         ('B9', 2) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
         ('B9', 3) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('E22', 1) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('E22', 2) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('E22', 3) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('X18', 1) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('X18', 2) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        ('X18', 3) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary

4 Declarations: E W X_index X
```

Comment: For your point 3, it depends of the instances. For example it would have been possible that employees 3  & 4 had a different set of WE like Friday, Saturday, Sunday. That's why I need to create one for each employees. Btw thank you for your complete response !